# The orchard asp.net cms. Is it an open source?

Tags: orchardcms

The orchard asp.net cms. Is it an open source?Because In my all downloads i found that some dll in BIN directory.That why, i got this doubt.Please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated on **[http://orchard.codeplex.com/](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=orchard)**

> Orchard is a **free, open source, community-focused project** aimed at delivering applications and reusable components on the ASP.NET platform.

The **[download page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227212540/http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/69668)** should quickly help you to retrieve the source code. Check the **"Orchard.Source.1.3.10.zip"** (where *1.13.10* is the latest stable version) link in the "Other Available Downloads" section.

Provided you're willing to retrieve the latest **development** version of the code, switch to the ["Source code"](https://web.archive.org/web/20121017153710/http://orchard.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/changesets?ProjectName=orchard) tab and click the **Download** link.

[image: Download link screenshot]

Comment: Yes. Dependencies are integrated as compiled dlls, but each of them is itself open source and is accompanied of its license and pedigree. The source code of dependencies is never included, that's normal.